# Trying to get a mouse hover zoom transistion effect using html and css but image is getting overflowed, the images position are getting altered

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions, mouseover

I am new to HTML and CSS. i was trying to get the mouse hover zoom transition on the images. I am able to get the transition with no issue but i dont want it to overflow the size of the image which changes with the size of the page. here is both css and html code. I am having issues in the ".img-outer" part of the css code.

```css
img {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
}

/* .img-outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 30%;
  max-height: 30%;
} */

.img-inner {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

p {
  font-family: "Bebas Neue";
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 1.6%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  color: rgb(77, 75, 75);
}

#name {
  font-family: "Bebas Neue";
  font-size: 23px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-top: 1.5%;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="photostyle.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Photo Blog</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="name">BLOG NAME</p>
    <p>Mono Photographs</p>

    <div class="img-outer">
      <div class="img-inner">
        <img
          src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8450/8026519634_f33f3724ea_b.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="img-outer">
      <div class="img-inner">
        <img
          src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7218/7209301894_c99d3a33c2_h.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="img-outer">
      <div class="img-inner">
        <img
          src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7231/6947093326_df216540ff_b.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="img-outer">
      <div class="img-inner">
        <img
          src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8788/17367410309_78abb9e5b6_b.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="img-outer">
      <div class="img-inner">
        <img
          src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5814/20700286354_762c19bd3b_b.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="img-outer">
      <div class="img-inner">
        <img
          src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5647/21137202535_404bf25729_b.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="img-outer">
      <div class="img-inner">
        <img
          src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5588/14991687545_5c8e1a2e86_b.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="img-outer">
      <div class="img-inner">
        <img
          src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3888/14878097108_5997041006_b.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="img-outer">
      <div class="img-inner">
        <img
          src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7579/15482110477_0b0e9e5421_b.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the solution.

```css
.img-outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
}

.img-inner {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  width:100%;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

p {
  font-family: "Bebas Neue";
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 1.6%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  color: rgb(77, 75, 75);
}

#name {
  font-family: "Bebas Neue";
  font-size: 23px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-top: 1.5%;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
    <p id="name">BLOG NAME</p>
    <p>Mono Photographs</p>

    <div class="img-outer">
      <div class="img-inner">
        <img
          src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8450/8026519634_f33f3724ea_b.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="img-outer">
      <div class="img-inner">
        <img
          src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7218/7209301894_c99d3a33c2_h.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="img-outer">
      <div class="img-inner">
        <img
          src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7231/6947093326_df216540ff_b.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="img-outer">
      <div class="img-inner">
        <img
          src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8788/17367410309_78abb9e5b6_b.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="img-outer">
      <div class="img-inner">
        <img
          src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5814/20700286354_762c19bd3b_b.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="img-outer">
      <div class="img-inner">
        <img
          src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5647/21137202535_404bf25729_b.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="img-outer">
      <div class="img-inner">
        <img
          src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5588/14991687545_5c8e1a2e86_b.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="img-outer">
      <div class="img-inner">
        <img
          src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3888/14878097108_5997041006_b.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="img-outer">
      <div class="img-inner">
        <img
          src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7579/15482110477_0b0e9e5421_b.jpg"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
```